# How can i use my local mysqldump through ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, mysql, tunnel

I would like to dump a mysql-database with mysqldump. But: This command isn't installed on the remote server.

It is possible to use my local mysqldump command, to connect via an ssh tunnel to achieve this? I found several solutions, but each one required the mysqldump command directly on the server.

When I use Sequel Pro (an Mac OS X App), I can perform an export via an SSH tunnel. But this is not the fastest solution and cannot be used on a unix server...

Answer (score 1):

Build an SSH tunnel:

```
ssh user@host -L 3306:localhost:3306
```

and then use `mysqldump`:

```
mysqldump -h localhost  [more options]
```

Note that this will not be any faster than what Sequel Pro does, it's essentially exactly the same approach.